# OAuth Token Rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to confirm the token grant rate for Oauth authentication. Since the token grant rate is limited to 100 times / minute, will it be limited to the grant rate if one tenant tries to obtain tokens for 100 users or more?
The following is a supplement
Currently, we are considering using a script to obtain tokens for a large number of users and using Dovecot's proxy function to access Gmail.
I'm thinking of getting tokens automatically every 30 to 60 minutes from the expiration date of the token. However, I am concerned that I will be limited to the token grant rate. Ultimately, we are assuming the use of about 10,000 users, and if it is 100 cases / minute, we are concerned that it will take 100 minutes to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your application has been approved (verified). If not, review this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) first.

Google OAuth access tokens are valid for 3,600 seconds. On the first authorization request, request a refresh token and save it (typically in a database). The refresh token is valid for a longer period of time (days but is not a constant). The refresh token does expire and can be revoked for a number of reasons. Once an access token expires, request a new access token using the refresh token. Once a refresh token expires or is revoked, the user must authenticate again.

By following that design, you will minimize requesting tokens. In your case, you can request an [OAuth Quota](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_quota_increase) increase.

[Gmail: Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)